# Do not add a event click

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datatemplate

When you add a Click event throws System.NullReferenceException.

```
<ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" DataContext="{Binding idPerson, Converter={StaticResource ConvertTrainersFromClientsKey}}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <DockPanel>
    <Button Content="{Binding name_trainer}" Tag="{Binding idPersonTrainer}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Click="Button_Click"/>//this Button_Click
    <DockPanel>
     <TextBlock Text="Окончание заявки: "/>
     <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxIsReadOnly}" Text="{Binding date_payment}"/>
    </DockPanel>
   </DockPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

without the event everything works fine

event code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

edit:

complete code in which the event in another element works well in right there.

```
<ListView DockPanel.Dock="Top" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="datagrid" Loaded="datagrid_Loaded" ItemsSource="{Binding Client}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                <Border Margin="10" Width="100" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="LightBlue" CornerRadius="2"  >
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Image Source="{Binding photo, Converter={StaticResource ConvertNullImageKey}}"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
                <DockPanel Margin="10" Width="{Binding BindingGroupName=dockwidth}">
                    <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxIsReadOnly}" Text="{Binding name_client}"/>
                    <Label Content="Сопровождающий" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
                    <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="listbox" DataContext="{Binding idPerson, Converter={StaticResource ConvertTrainersFromClientsKey}}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <Button Content="{Binding name_trainer}" Tag="{Binding idPersonTrainer}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
                                    <DockPanel>
                                        <TextBlock Text="Окончание заявки: "/>
                                        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxIsReadOnly}" Text="{Binding date_payment}"/>
                                    </DockPanel>

                                </DockPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                    <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Нету" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=listbox, Converter={StaticResource ConvertTrainersFromClientsVisibilityKey}}"/>
                </DockPanel>
                <Grid Margin="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="Дата рождения" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Адрес" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Телефон" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Email" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Партнер" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Margin="5"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding date_reg}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  Margin="5"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding address}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  Margin="5"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding phone}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"  Margin="5"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding mail}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5"/>
                    <Button Content="{Binding namePartner}" Click="Button_Click_1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Margin="5"/>
                </Grid>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="False"  Margin="10">
                    <Button Content="Редактировать" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10" x:Name="p_editStudent" Click="p_editStudent_Click"  VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Button Tag="{Binding idPerson}" Content="Переписка" Margin="10" x:Name="p_allMessages" Click="p_allMessages_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Button Content="Написать письмо" Margin="10" x:Name="p_sendMessageForStudent" Click="p_sendMessageForStudent_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </DockPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

is work

```
<Button Content="{Binding namePartner}" Click="Button_Click_1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Margin="5"/>
```

click not work

```
<Button Content="{Binding name_trainer}" Tag="{Binding idPersonTrainer}" Click="Button_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
```

Comment: Could you post the stack trace for the NullReferenceException?

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of the object." - this is my translate from russian to english.

Answer (score 0):

your click event should be protected or public. The XAML and the code behind are partial classes hence the XAML cant access the click event if its defined in the other partial class and declared private

Comment: no, event work because I found a property x: Class = namespace class class where the event to be. And as he was then swear at compile

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing. In the end I was having an outdated incompatible version of .NET Framework, is all. Updating from .NET 4.0 to 4.5.1 solved the issue.